# How to use WordPress for class notes?

Tags: users, hosting

I've been writing my C++ class' notes directly into my WordPress editor. My professor has tasked me with codifying the notes for future use. I'm working with a classmate on this project, but I need to give her access to my blog.

Additionally, my notes are written in a narrative style, which means that a lot of the notes will be edited. I'd like to preserve a copy of the originals.

My WordPress blog is hosted with GoDaddy as an installed application. I don't know if I can add another user that can access only one specific category.

What's the best way to do add access? Can I allow a user to edit only one category? Is there a way to add a separate WordPress blog to my GoDaddy account?

**Edit:**

I've tried to enable Network setup and I've managed to thoroughly botch my .htaccess file. My blog is in the subdirectory called "wordpress". What can I do to get my wp-config and my .htacess back up and running? What would the default look like for my setup?

Comment: Please post your edit as a separate question since it really is a separate issue.  Also, this is not a support forum ... if you need immediate help, try the [official support forums](http://wordpress.org/support) or check into the #WordPress room on IRC.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation would be to add a separate site (usually pretty easy to do ... just follow the typical installation instructions).

Then, you can *export* your current content into an XML file and *import* it into the new site.

#### A Better Option

Create a *new* site on WordPress.com and import your content there.  This has the benefit of being easier to set up, allows you to add other authors, and doesn't require you to keep hosting it in the future.

It also means you can keep your class notes online for future classes (and give ownership of the site and content to others in the future).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the Export as XML to save a copy of the current WordPress site.  But, the XML copy of the site does not port over any images, audio/video, docx, or PDFs, etc. that you might have included in your notes.

It is also possible to run a multi-site instance of WordPress from a USB stick (4GB+), or laptop.  http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/14998/turn-your-flash-drive-into-a-portable-web-server/
*I haven't done this in about a year, but have successfully done this quite a few times.  As long as you have Internet connectivity, you should be able to copy from your current WP site down to the copy site (wherever it is located) and with the option to copy images, etc.

http://fsuwebtools.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/wordpress-on-a-stick/

http://fsuwebtools.wordpress.com/2011/07/29/wordpress-on-a-stick-2/